# Why Autowire of class Validator not working but working for GeneralValidator?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired, spring-validator

I have came across a weird behavior in my java class and wanted to understand what is the cause of such behavior, since investigating online didn't result with anything similar to my situation, I had to ask.

My java program using Spring Framework has a class named `Validator`, it's definition is as follows:

```
@Component
public class Validator {
...
}
```

Now, in many other places in my code I use this class with `@Autowired` annotation, like:

```
@Autowired
Validator validator;
```

When I try to fire up my service my `.war` fails with error:
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.company.common.validators.Validator]`

But if I add name to the `@Component` annotation like this:

```
@Component("Validator")
public class Validator {
...
}
```

it works perfectly fine.

Why do I have to state the name of the validator class in the `@Component` annotation, when it is the same name? I have noticed that if I change my class name to anything else, for example: `GeneralValidator` it works fine without stating the name in the `@Component`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of a conflict with org.springframework.validation.Validator (documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html)), please note the documentation of the optional argument for the @Component ([here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html))

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

Comment: just to make clear, so what you are saying is that when I use the `@Component` annotation it defines my class as spring Bean and since it already has spring framework interface with that name, in my classpath it won't create any of them unless I specifically ask him to? and that is why with another name it is working?